# WinDbg session variables - Aliases vs. User-Defined Pseudo-Registers

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

I need to hold a specific value (a string, to be exact) **throughout the lifetime of a single WinDbg session**.

The reason for that, is that I need to address this variable in a few places throughout the lifetime of the WinDbg session (through `.if` statements, to be exact), and I want it to be defined at the startup of the session - using an argument that'll be passed. It can't be undefined or disposed - I must be able to address it in any point in the debugging session, and of course I don't want to risk that it might be redefined.

I was thinking of using a file for that purpose, or a shared memory, but I much prefer to solve this using *WinDbg scripting*. 
If it's possible, it's obviously a much more elegant solution.

I've done some reading online on this matter and the issue is that I couldn't find a reference where the differences between **Aliases** (defined by an `aS` command) and **User-Defined Pseudo-Registers** (the registers in the range `$t0..$t19`, which are accessed by using the `r` command) were described. I couldn't find really understand the use cases for each.

The seemed to me **Aliases** is the better option, due to the fact that they can be named, in contrast to **User-Defined Pseudo-Registers** which have set names (wasn't sure regarding how to pick the "right" registered, to minimize possible collisions with other scripts which might use it, or is there any difference at all).

Am I missing something here? 
Which should I use in this case, or are they both unsuitable for this situation?

Comment: WAT? Aliases are the ones that can be named and the pseudo-registers are the ones that have set names. You just said that one paragraph above.

Comment: You might want to consider using the JS integration. It seems a lot less awful than the WinDbg scripting language.

Comment: @conio edited, just a logical typo :)

Comment: @conio wasn't that added only in the latest insider preview?

Comment: No, it's been there for a year already. See [New Insider SDK and JavaScript Extensibility!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windbg/2016/10/27/new-insider-sdk-and-javascript-extensibility/).

Comment: @conio thanks for the link!